# Checkbox value to search table to show row if value matches row ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, toggle

I am looking to use the checkboxes in the form to search through the below table and update the CSS class so that they are no longer hidden. Have tried a few attempts at a function with no luck.

Hoping for some help on how to construct the `searchTable()` function to loop through the table and match the value from the checkbox against the `tr` id value.

!***Update***!

I have been trying to use Jquery toggle() to show/hide the table rows with no luck but hoping I am now not too far away. Using vanilla HTML, CSS and JS as a "work project" on a business device.

```html
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
      $("#" + inputValue).toggle();
  });
});</script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="system1" value="B">B</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="system2" value="C">C</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="system3" value="BII">BII</label>

    <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr class="hidden" id="B">  
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Tran</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2, skill-3</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2</td>
      <td>skill-1</td>
      <td> 
        <select name="levels" id="levels">
        <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
        <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
        <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
        </select> 
      </td>
    </tr> <tr class="hidden" id="BII">  
      <td>BII</td>
      <td>Tran</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2, Skill-3</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2</td>
      <td>skill-1</td>
      <td> 
        <select name="levels" id="levels">
        <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
        <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
        <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
        </select> 
      </td>
    </tr> <tr class="hidden" id="C">  
      <td>C</td>
      <td>Auth</td>
      <td>skill-1,skill-2,Skill-3</td>
      <td>skill-1,skill-2</td>
      <td>skill-1</td>
      <td> 
        <select name="levels" id="levels">
        <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
        <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
        <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
        </select> 
      </td>
    </tr> </tbody>
```

Comment: What do you have for searchTable() so far? What library or framework are you using?

Comment: I have moved on from that funtion and trying to use JQuery toggle function with no luck as of yet. @RokoC.Buljan thank you VS Code had applied the extra form tag I have removed.

Comment: @o you have no `<table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any `searchTable()` function, but you can actually accomplish this in pure CSS using the `:checked` pseudo-class and the general sibling selector (`~`) and then targeting the row.

Take a look:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th, table td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
table th input, table th select, table td input, table td select {
  margin: -5px -10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
}
[name="systems"] ~ #myTable tr[id] {
  display: none;
}
[name="systems"]#system1:checked ~ #myTable tr#B,
[name="systems"]#system2:checked ~ #myTable tr#C,
[name="systems"]#system3:checked ~ #myTable tr#BII {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="system1" value="B"> <label for="system1">BNS</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="system2" value="C"> <label for="system2">CMAS</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="system3" value="BII"> <label for="system3">Base II</label>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="B">
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Tran</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2, skill-3</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2</td>
      <td>skill-1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="levels" id="levels">
          <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
          <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
          <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="BII">
      <td>BII</td>
      <td>Tran</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2, Skill-3</td>
      <td>skill-1, skill-2</td>
      <td>skill-1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="levels" id="levels">
          <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
          <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
          <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="C">
      <td>C</td>
      <td>Auth</td>
      <td>skill-1,skill-2,Skill-3</td>
      <td>skill-1,skill-2</td>
      <td>skill-1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="levels" id="levels">
          <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
          <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
          <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the above, I did try this with no luck, the display: none wasn't even working and it was before. I am looking at JQuery now to try get this over the line,

Comment: @Owen Shaw ^this works as is, without any JavaScript needed. If you click "Run Code Snippet" you can see it work. If this did not work for you, please let me know what were steps were so I can try to reproduce them, but this should work as is in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working with below.

````
<label><input type="checkbox" name="systems" id="B1" value="B" onclick="showTable()">B</label>

```function showTable() {
  var x = document.getElementById("B");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}```
````